# MS Project replicates all Master Project tasks within each subproject

Tags: ms-project

I'm using MS Project 2021 desktop.  I've created a Master Project, and about 14 subprojects under that.  I'm using a Resource Pool which each subproject can draw resources from.

The issue is, somehow each subproject now contains ALL of the subprojects/tasks from the Master Project.  Each subproject should contain only its own tasks.

Has anyone experienced this issue?  Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Screen shots would be helpful--edit your post to include a few.

Comment: In addition to the screen shots suggested by Rachel, it would help to know exactly how you created your master and the resource pool.

Comment: Rachel, still working on the screenshots.  May have to come up with a like example due to proprietary restrictons.

Comment: John, each of the subprojects was  created before the master project.  Each of the subprojects contains all the possible level of effort tasks to be performed by any team individual.  No actual assignments of resources have been made at this point; that will be made from the resource pool as assignments and percent of task devotion are known.  The master project was then created, adding each of the subprojects.  Calling up any one subproject now finds ALL subprojects included.

Comment: The idea here was to to be able to detect overallocation of any of about 18 resources listed in the pool, once assignments have been made.

Comment: You say each of the subprojects contains ALL the possible LOE tasks to be performed by any team individual (resource). That sounds like each subproject has all tasks so I would expect any subproject to show everything. Here's where that screenshot would be very helpful. As far as detecting overallocation, that info will show up in the Task Usage or Resource Usage view on the pool file.

Comment: I've solved my self-inflicted problem.  After seeing a vague reference in a master/subproject video, I realized it has to do with how you insert a subproject.  If you insert a subproject, WITH EXISTING SUBPROJECTS EXPANDED, Project considers the added subproject as being under the existing subproject, not as a separate subproject.  I tried it with only one subproject line showing, no "duplication".  Thanks for your thinking which led me down the correct path.